# Xen Hypervisor boots to a black screen after installation

Tags: grub2, 20.04, xen

I wanted to try virtualization so I went with Xen and followed this guide:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Xen

I got to the second command which says

> Now reboot:

```
$ sudo reboot
```

During rebot, grub decided to boot Xen, and it goes through a bunch of code, whooshing by faster than I can blink, and when the boot sequence is done (or at least I think it is) the sceen blinks and then the sceen tells me there is no signal and goes to sleep.

I am using Ubuntu 20.04, trying to install Xen Hypervisor

Comment: You have not said that you followed all the instructions on the link you gave.

Comment: Are you being serious...?